Is there a paradox in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem?
The Gödel Incompleteness Theorem was a major discovery in modern logic that has consistently attracted the attention of scientific and philosophical circles.
However, since the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem was put forward, the scientific and philosophical significance of its proof has been questioned; in particular, Wittgenstein regarded it as a certain logical paradox. In Gödel’s view, Wittgenstein does not understand the incompleteness theorem; Gödel said,

He interpreted it as a logical paradox that, but in fact, on the
contrary, is a mathematical theorem of an undisputed part of
mathematics (limited number theory or combinatorial mathematics).”
(Wang Hao, 2009, p227).

Who is right?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I closed as pushing a personal philosophy because the answers and discussion in comments made apparent that this was solely posted to promote your own ideas in the matter.

Gödel was right. O'Connor 2005 meets every known objection: it is constructive and finite, indeed it runs on commodity hardware in reasonable time; it includes Rosser's trick, it is not relative to ZFC, it addresses first-order axioms, and a large body of empirical work endorses the correctness of the proof in terms of both hardware and software. Smith 2007 rebuilds Gödel's approach using all of the tools developed by his contemporaries. Lawvere 2006 explains how Gödel's theorem is a special case of Lawvere's 1967 fixed-point theorem, and how the latter theorem is proved without any self-referential techniques; Yanofsky 2003 contextualizes Lawvere's theorem by showing that many apparently-self-referential paradoxes neatly decompose as special cases.
There is an important philosophical lesson here. Sometimes a philosopher — here, Wittgenstein — is wrong. Their reputation and prior work are irrelevant. The strength of their opinion and the beauty of their justification are irrelevant. Only the evidence presented is relevant. For mathematics, formal proof is very strong evidence, and insightful analogies are even stronger evidence; Gödel provided the (first) proof, and Lawvere provided the analogy.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive: If you have any evidence against Lawvere's theorem, we have an active discussion happening in chat and you're invited to share. The thing is that I'm honestly not inclined to talk to folks who can't work through either Smith (syntactic) or Yanofsky (semantic); the entirety of logic and maths shifted from about 1880 to 1970, and we need to keep up. It's no different from the rest of postmodernism.

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive: On a personal note: I suspect that you think of Gödel deniers as relatively harmless. This is not my first conversation with such a person; I was involved in debunking the notorious sockpuppeteer Carl Hewitt and the damage he did is still being cleaned up even though he can't ever contribute again. I recommend reading Dudley 1992 or Dudley 1996 ("The Trisectors", one of my favorites.) We must meet cranks head-on.

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive I find it hard to read past the cursing, because there's nothing there. Maybe you could say why you object to this answer instead of spouting rude nonsense.

Godel's diagonal lemma is the key to construct Godel's formula. We allow this construction, but we construct a contradiction, and this formula leads to a paradox. If there is no problem with the diagonal lemma, then there is only a problem with our formal system, as there is with naive set theory.

@ZhangHong: There's no problem with the diagonal lemma and also no problem with our formal systems. Incompleteness is a feature which naturally arises. If there is a problem, it is with our inability to accept incompleteness.

@Corbin The proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem must be wrong, because in its proof I find a paradox similar to Russell's paradox, which is based entirely on classical logic.

@Corbin Godel's diagonal lemma is the key to proving Godel's incompleteness theorem. However, the basis of this lemma is primitive recursion, but the proof of this lemma violates the primitive recursion, and thus leads to the failure of the proof.

Godel's diagonal lemma is the key to proving Godel's incompleteness theorem. But in the proof of this lemma, assigning the same values to two variables in a formula that conforms to primitive recursion causes a self-loop, breaking the formula's primitive recursion. Thus discrediting the very basis of their existence. Therefore, Godel's incompleteness theorem is derived from the wrong method, and therefore must fail.

In Wittgenstein's competition with Godel and Cantor, there is no doubt that the former is the real king. The paradox of infinite exchange proves that Cantor's diagonal method is a trick. The essence of Godel's diagonal lemma is self-reference, leaving the original recursion, which leads to self-circulation, and eventually leads to a paradox appearing in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

What is the paradox of infinite Exchange：https://www.researchgate.net/publication/380402226_Philosophical_infinity_and_mathematical_infinity

What is the paradox in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem：https://www.researchgate.net/publication/380185464_Some_Questions_On_the_Proof_of_the_Godel_Incompleteness_Theorem

@ZhangHong: We already covered your papers in chat. You say "the proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem must be wrong." Show us. Since O'Connor's 2005 proof is computer-checked, you need to demonstrate that there is a flaw in the underlying formalism, and since the system is based on the calculus of constructions, an element of the lambda cube, it is strongly normalizing and enjoys uniqueness of types. Basically, find a bug in Coq which invalidates their proof.

You'll also need to find a flaw in Lawvere 1967, which amounts to showing that Cartesian-closed category theory is always inconsistent. I wouldn't bother looking for this one, but it's worth thinking about for an afternoon. When you're done, note that the lambda cube includes Cartesian-closed categories at the bottom and so you're back to fighting against Coq and Barendregt.

@Corbin You always emphasize this, emphasize that, why don't you seriously study the paradox presented in my paper? And this paradox comes from our classical logic.

@Corbin You can find this paradox in my paper, or at the end of the discussion board on this issue.

@Corbin I have pointed out the crux of the matter. The proof of Godel's diagonal lemma, for example, was a classic mistake. Our original discussion was based on primitive recursion, but then the proof of the lemma deviated from the primitive recursion, resulting in a self-referential proposition, and so deceived ourselves. This goes against the grain of mathematical rigor.

A formula that satisfies primitive recursion must have a limit on its variables. Not just a skin bag. Otherwise, we will go to the opposite of the theorem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Corbin, gracias for your reply to my "answer". I'd like to pick your brain on an analogy between math and English. Gödel makes a syntactic claim and by that I understand math allows, e.g., the expression (say) X is Y and we can see what happens when X = theorem and Y = unprovable. In English too X is Y is syntactically sound and if we let X = theorem and Y = unprovable we have the same problem, oui?

You do not understand the incompleteness theorem. It does not require "coding", and it does not depend on "actual infinity", and it does not "hide" any paradox. You cannot reject it as long as you accept basic facts about finite binary strings.

Don't be too dogmatic, please reflect on what is wrong with the science of mathematical logic.

This answer is unnecessarily combative. The OP does not assert an understanding in their question.  The OP doesn't claim to know what the correct answer is. It asks a question about two claims.  Whether the OP understands the theorem or not has no bearing on whether Wittgenstein is correct in his assertion about it.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I kind of see where you are coming from, but all the comments I see seem to reference documented arguments except for one which I read as a continuation of the one before.  The OP is asking for an explanation, not just assertions and I don't see the issue with that.

@JimmyJames The comments to the question by the OP references an article written by the author of the OP which is nonsense and demonstrates a complete lack of understanding of the incompleteness theorem. As such, this answer by user21820 is perfectly justified.

@Bumble That's a fair point.  I somehow missed that the OP and the author were the same.  I still think the general idea of the question is a good one i.e. "what did Wittgenstein misunderstand about this" regardless of whether the way the OP asked is problematic.

@Bumble I did find a good explanation of the theorem in the upvoted answer here ;).

Why is Godel's incompleteness theorem wrong：Wittgenstein saw Godel's proof as a paradox. In the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem, Godel concludes that neither Godel's formula nor its negation can be proved, and this is only one of the results. Godel obviously neglected another result, that is, if Godel's formula is true, then it follows that Godel's formula is not true; And if Godel's formula is not true, we can deduce that Godel's formula is true. This is clearly a paradox.

Any formal system is essentially a set theoretic system. Since naive set theory hides Russell's paradox, the formal system must also hide a similar Russell paradox. Thanks to Godel for finding this paradox, the Godel's formula. And the core idea behind this is the view of actual  infinity. In my opinion, actual infinity is a self-contradiction, and it always has been.

Modern formal systems do not add the necessary new axioms to restrict itself like axiom set theory ZFC, which inevitably leads to its own inherent paradoxes.

@‍Joshua: I said precisely what is correct in my answer. Additionally, the theorem has nothing to do with GR.

@‍ZhangHong: That is utter nonsense. Formal systems do not need to be set theories. And you are deliberately ignoring the fact that the incompleteness theorem has zilch to do with actual infinity. If you do not wish to learn mathematics, that's the end.

@user21820 The judgment of oneself is a kind of actual infinite thought.

@user21820 Please read my paper：https://www.researchgate.net/publication/377571704_Turing_Machine_Halting_Problem_Russell's_Paradox_and_Godel_Incompleteness_Theorem

@user21820: Actually it does. Suppose the halting problem had a solution. The situation changes; and Godel's construction doesn't work anymore. That's what I found in GR; the situation is inverted and the most powerful machine can solve the halting problem for Turing machines while itself having a trivial halting problem. This takes GR outside of first order logic; and despite being mathematically sound, Godel's theorem is effectively false here.

@‍Joshua: No. Stop confusing yourself and others. Gödel's theorem has very clear conditions. It doesn't matter whether the halting problem can be solved or not. The theorem is correct, regardless of whether you believe it applies to something or not.

@user21820 Can you explain the paradox presented in my article? If you can't explain it, then I suggest you seriously study the science of mathematical logic, the philosophy of mathematics, because the philosophy of mathematics is wonderful.

Zhang, you do not wish to learn mathematics, so that's the end.

In an appendix to Part I of Remarks on The Foundations Of Mathematics, Wittgenstein criticized the following argument:

I imagine someone asking my advice; he says: “I have constructed a proposition (I will use ‘P’ to designate it) in Russell’s symbolism, and by means of certain definitions and transformations it can be so interpreted that it says: ‘P is not provable in Russell’s system’. Must I not say that this proposition on the one hand is true, and on the other hand is unprovable? For suppose it were false; then it is true that it is provable. And that surely cannot be! And if it is proved, then it is proved that it is not provable. Thus it can only be true, but unprovable.”

(Translation by G.E.M. Anscombe; can be viewed with the original German here.)
The surrounding text seems to be a reasonable takedown of that argument. That argument is what many people believe to be Gödel's argument—enough that it is worth putting some effort into showing that it's wrong—but it's not Gödel's actual argument, which doesn't depend on a notion of truth.
Whether Wittgenstein was one of those who believed that that was Gödel's argument, I don't know. He didn't explicitly say so, nor otherwise. If he believed he was criticizing Gödel's theorem in that section then he was wrong.

"For suppose it were false; then it is true that it is provable." is this what "many people believe to be Gödel's argument"?

@JimmyJames I think so, yes. People very often say that Gödel showed a certain proposition is true but unprovable.

That seems like an unreasonably shallow interpretation and that's coming from someone who is quite sure I have a very limited understanding of this. The example I anchor on is "the set of all sets that don't contain themselves" and that Gödel showed that there must be at least one such irreconcilable statement in any logic that can incorporate arithmetic. Is that roughly on target?

Any formal system is a set theory.@JimmyJames

@JimmyJames: Not at all. It seems that ZFC does not prove the existence of "the set of all sets that don't contain themselves", and the incompleteness theorem applies to it whether or not it does. What is your mathematical background, and do you know programming? If you tell me, then I can guide you to a complete understanding of the incompleteness theorem very quickly.

@user21820 The ZFC axiomatic set theory system is essentially a system with potentially infinite properties.

@user21820 " It seems that ZFC does not prove the existence of "the set of all sets that don't contain themselves" Who said it does?  I sure didn't.

@user21820 "What is your mathematical background," Undergrad: calc, linear algebra, some discrete mathematics.  "and do you know programming?" Yes.

@ZhangHong: The well-known formal system MIU is not a set theory; it has neither functions nor composition nor elementhood.

@JimmyJames: Ok then please read "Incompleteness theorems" linked from my profile. You should be able to understand up to "Explicitly independent sentence", which suffices to understand the theorem, within a day. Regarding "set of all sets that ...", your original comment does not make sense, since naive set theory was inconsistent, so the incompleteness theorem says nothing about it, whereas we believe ZFC is consistent, so the incompleteness theorem says something non-trivial about it. That's the point; the theorem has absolutely nothing to do with Russell's paradox.

@user21820 "That's the point; the theorem has absolutely nothing to do with Russell's paradox." OK. I'm not sure why I associated the two.

@user21820 I suggest you read the philosophical journey written by Wang Hao.  Wang Hao, the one who talked and talked to Godel.

Cogito ... Gödel's argument is that in a given axiomatic system capable of math, call it A, there is a statement/mathematical theorem, call it T, such that:

T is true
T is unprovable in A

A few points that are non liquet:

Did Gödel prove an unprovable?
In deductive logic at least it would be the case that T is true IFF T is proven (for that T has to be provable) or some weaker version of that. How come then that T is true AND T is unprovable? At a minimum this is counterintuitive.

From what I've read in the posts, my reading of Gödel's argument is way off the mark; it seems he's not claiming that there's a mathematical theorem T that's true and blah blah blah. At least there's no controversy here regarding unprovability.
Another thing I don't understand is why Gödel's paradox (if I may call it that) and its implications are accepted while Russell's paradox prompted a revision of set theory, specifically to rid math of the paradox?
Yet another issue is that if the Gödel sentence G asserts G is unprovable, how is that different from the proof-variant of the liar paradox viz. This sentence is unprovable? I recall reading Gödel admitted to using a spinoff of the liar sentence.

The fundamental reason why the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem is wrong is that it destroys the basic principle of representability. "Representability" is equivalent to “recursion", and Godel's formula obviously does not have the property of "recursion". Wittgenstein saw through the cloud. So, for Wittgenstein, there are no true and unprovable propositions.

@ZhangHong, I don't know what representability is, but I wouldn't go so far as to say Gödel is wrong for the reason that I've heard/seen people actually mention the mathematical theorem(s) that is/are true but unprovable. However, I have no idea how they determined said theorem(s) to be true sans proof that they are.

The representability principle is equivalent to recursion. A formula that loops itself obviously cannot be recursive. Wittgenstein discovered this problem.

My paper completely debunked Godel's view. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/383620550_On_the_Paradox_Hidden_in_the_Proof_of_Godel's_Incompleteness_Theorem

@ZhangHong, I'm not qualified enough to read papers, but congratulations if you've saved mathematics. David Hilbert would be happy I suppose.

A few points. In the third paragraph: we say T is true in the standard model. There is no finite natural number which, interpreted as a proof in A, proves T. It is consistent to let T be false axiomatically, in which case there is some non-standard natural number which codes the proof of T in a non-computable fashion.

Fourth paragraph is one POV. Here's another: Russell's paradox prompted us to throw out some of Frege's axioms, not all of them; set theory survived. There are plenty of non-ZFC axioms of similar power, like ETCS, which reinvent set theory for other reasons. Meanwhile, Gödel's theorems brought Hilbert's programme to a complete halt and was a tough pill to swallow; legend is that only Von Neumann and Hilbert understood what Gödel had shown, and only Von Neumann approved.

Fifth paragraph: In a certain sense, the sense of the liar's sentence encoding a negation, yes: they're the same argument and Lawvere showed that in 1967. However, Gödel's proof is syntactic, which means that we can verify it by manipulating formal symbols according to objective rules. This is in contrast to the semantic understanding of the liar's sentence, which begs the assumption that it must be either true or false. Indeed, Tarski used Gödel's argument to show that semantic truth cannot be defined formally.

@Corbin, 99% of this is beyond my ken, but when you say Gödel's theorem is syntactic do you mean that it's like x is y to z (as far as I can tell this is syntactic in English because of the variables). Then we're doing language instead of subject (is math a language)? Would I be correct then to say that Gödel proved a certain linguistic expression (Gödel sentence G asserting its own unprovability) is perfectly grammatical in any given axiomatic system?

@Corbin, I wonder how Gödel proved the completeness of 1st order logic? Isn't there a corresponding Gödel sentence G for logic? For example "Logic is nonsense", syntactically x is y

Wittgenstein's criticism can be summed up as "it is not true that Goedel's proof is purely syntactic, in fact it cannot be".  Wittgenstein was indeed very critical to the whole Aristotelian, Fregean, Russellian approach to logic.  And, for the chronicle, some even have it that in fact Wittgenstein was quite right, or at least that his objections are quite legitimate.
But, as a word of caution, one has to read and study W. himself, not his critics, at least not to begin with, in particular the mail correspondence between W. and Russell before and up to the Tractatus is quite illuminating as to the actual debates: just maybe keep in mind that W. is not any less misrepresented and misunderstood than Marx himself is...

Wittgenstein argues that the truth of Godel's "true and unprovable" proposition is so implausible that it cannot be used except by sophistry. Because Godel's formula itself is a paradox.

"the mail correspondence between W. and Russell before and up to the Tractatus is quite illuminating..." What is the link with the question? Godel's Theorem is later than Tractatus.

@MauroALLEGRANZA  "Godel's Theorem is later than Tractatus": yes, but we cannot understand Wittgenstein's objection to that theorem without knowing where it's coming from, otherwise it is not even possible to understand the terms or the analogies or the problems and the goals.

@ZhangHong  "Because Godel's formula itself is a paradox": I don't think so, the argument and its conclusion is not so much in question as the "standard" claim that the proof is purely syntactic, which is the result that is really at stake, since, put simply, if semantics has anything to do with it, then models in which G is false are simply false models (of arithmetic): and what that in fact entails generally in terms of Model Theory and its import.

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive My paper points out that there are paradoxes in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem. If this paradox is necessary, then the proof of Godel's theorem is wrong. We must find out the root cause of the mistake. In my opinion, any statement that refers to itself is a cycle, an actual infinity, and inevitably brings contradictions.

It seems to me that the entire Western logic community has been lying. My thesis clearly points out the paradox in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem, but the western philosophy circle has always avoided talking about it. They had blown the nervous Godel up to heaven, and it now seemed that this was the greatest harm to him.

The entire Western inculture and incivility is founded on abuse, lies, corruption and vileness indeed since inception, although the triumph of "capitalism" is the true and final demise of any life and decency on this planet: I mean, surely on this hemisphere. Just nothing paradoxical about it, humans are simply the most retarded species in this galaxy, our brain rather being our madness and curse, we just can't do the right thing ever... just no logical paradox in sight, but, out of curiosity, I will read your article and let you know if (IMO) there is in fact anything to it...

I agree there is a "problem of Infinity" in current mathematics and mathematical logic, tracing back to at least Cantorian set theory and Russellian logic.  But I disagree with the very premise in your analysis of GIT: in GIT the provability predicate (and only the provability predicate) is not primitive/fully recursive, and Goedel does not assume otherwise. -- To my understanding, the role of semantics in GIT is the only possible point of contention: before that, take it with PM...  (I won't add more, this is beyond your initial question.)

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive  The relation (in the model) corresponding to the predicate W is primitive recursive, and if Godel's formula is a valid formula, it will not find the relation corresponding to the model. Because Godel's formula is a self-loop, it is certainly not primitive recursion.

In Wittgenstein's competition with Godel and Cantor, there is no doubt that the former is the real king. The essence of Godel's diagonal lemma is self-reference, leaving the original recursion, which leads to self-circulation, and eventually leads to a paradox appearing in the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Wittgenstein firmly denied the rationality of this Gödel formula. He pointed out that, "Here the constructed proposition is just another expression of the constructed number. It has the shape of a proposition, but in comparison with other propositions, we cannot regard it as some symbol which expresses something, which has some meaning.". Since the "translation rule" (i.e., the Gödel code) does not change the original recursion of the original arithmetic proposition, Wittgenstein argues that "Gödel's proposition, which speaks of itself, does not refer to itself.”

That is, according to the principle of representability, Gödel's formula cannot talk about or judge itself.

In my paper, there are two core ideas that are mutually corroborating and well-documented.

I found a paradox in the proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem and found the concrete form of the paradox. This is, first of all, a new discovery, and one that has been overlooked. This obviously makes up for the weakness of Wittgenstein's argument.
Gödel's formula is a cyclic expression. This is obviously not recursive and thus violates the principle of representability. Therefore, it is also obviously absurd that we should discuss this Gödel's formula only outside the valid domain of the predicate W.


The general proof of Godel's Incompleteness Theorem is based on a "fixed point lemma". There is also a cycle in the "fixed point lemma", that is, Godel's formula is a cyclic expression. It is this cycle that makes Godel's formula lose its "recursion" and thus also violates the principle of representability, which is the cornerstone of the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem. Therefore, it is also obviously absurd that we should discuss this Godel formula only outside the valid domain of the predicate W.  Wittgenstein found that this cycle broke the principle of representability.

The paradox certainly exists. Because first-order logical systems are essentially like naive set theory, they lack restrictions on the definition of propositions (as arbitrary elements in naive set theory), resulting in self-contradictory definitions such as Godel's formula. Just as we need to develop naive set theory into ZFC axiomatic set theory, we also need to improve first-order logical systems in order to avoid paradoxes.

A formula that satisfies primitive recursion must have a limit on its variables. Not just a skin bag. Otherwise, we will go to the opposite of the theorem.

I have pointed out the crux of the matter. The proof of Godel's diagonal lemma, for example, was a classic mistake. Our original discussion was based on primitive recursion, but then the proof of the lemma deviated from the primitive recursion, resulting in a self-referential proposition, and so deceived ourselves. This goes against the grain of mathematical rigor.

The fundamental reason why the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem is wrong is that it destroys the basic principle of representability. "Representability" is equivalent to "primitive recursion", and Godel's formula obviously does not have the property of "primitive recursion". Wittgenstein saw through the cloud.

@KristianBerry I found a paradox in the proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem and found the concrete form of the paradox. This is, first of all, a new discovery, and one that has been overlooked. This obviously makes up for the weakness of Wittgenstein's argument.
